# Azure DevOps pipeline is stuck at "Starting evaluation of codeql/csharp-queries/Telemetry/UnsupportedExternalAPIs.ql."

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am adding CodeQL checks to our repository for it to run when code is pushed to our branch. The code ql analyze task never finishes and it always stuck until the task fails at this step "Starting evaluation of codeql/csharp-queries/Telemetry/UnsupportedExternalAPIs.ql." of running "AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Analyze@1" task in an AzureDevOps Pipeline.

My repository contains multiple projects and multiple solutions (mainly written using .NET). Here is my YAML file's content:

```
# Advanced Security Dependency Scanning v1 for Whole project

# Scan for open source dependency vulnerabilities in your source code.



trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  


pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

#variables:
  #advancedsecurity.codeql.querysuite: security-extended
  #advancedsecurity.submittoadvancedsecurity: true
  #timeoutInMinutes: 360

steps:
  - task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1
    inputs:
      languages: 'csharp'

  - task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Autobuild@1
    displayName: 'Advanced Security AutoBuild'
  
  - task: AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1
    displayName: 'Advanced Security Dependency scanning'
  
  - task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Analyze@1
    displayName: 'Advanced Security Code Analyze'
    timeoutInMinutes: 360
  
  - task: AdvancedSecurity-Publish@1
```

**EDIT**
I've already [opened a ticket on CodeQL official repository](https://github.com/github/codeql/issues/15059) but no one has responded yet.

Comment: It seems to be a CodeQL issue. Find a similar ticket based on the error message : https://github.com/github/codeql/issues/10703. It's recommended to open a 
 ticket on the [Github CodeQL issues](https://github.com/github/codeql/issues) area for help. Besides, in case it's caused by the MS hosted agent (RAM or Disk space limits), please check if it has the same issue when using a self-hosted agent if possible.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Thank you for your comment. I've already opened a ticket there and they haven't responded yet, even the similar ticket that you've kindly pointed to hasn't been resolved yet.

Comment: What about using other MS Hosted agents except the `ubuntu-latest`? Just try switching to `ubuntu-20.04` or even Windows agent `windows-latest` to see if it has the same issue.

Comment: I've already checked windows-latest and the same problem occurs. I'll give a try to ubuntu-20.04

Comment: Yeah, please have a try for that. Besides, you mentioned that your repository contains multiple projects and multiple solutions. If the size of the code base you are trying to analyze requires more CPU and memory resources. It may experience performance or such stuck issues due to the limitations of Microsoft-hosted agents. So, If possible, please also try setting up and using a self-hosted agent with sufficient hardware configuration to see if it works.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Thank you for the suggestions. I've just tried using ubuntu-20.04 but same issue happens. Can I increase the memory and CPU for MS-hosted agents?

Comment: No, we cannot increase the memory and CPU for MS-hosted agents. It's controlled by MS (VM image). See [Microsoft-hosted agents limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations) for details. If Microsoft-hosted agents don't meet your needs, then you can deploy your own self-hosted agents.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT thank you so very much for your suggestions and help!

Comment: @brahimAmer Is it possible to share a demo repo which can reproduce the issue so that we can test and troubleshoot it accordingly?